# Restreaming HLS video source to RTMP using ffmpeg.autogen

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, rtmp

I am trying to write a C# restreaming class that will take HLS/m3u8 H264 encoded video streams and restream them as RTMP H264 encoded video.
I started with the simple transport stream recorder sample and was able to make it work in the following scenarios:
UDP restreamed to UDP (mpegts)
UDP restreamed to RTMP (flv)
HLS restreamed to UDP (mpegts)
But cannot for the life of me get it to work with HLS to RTMP.
I get a failure return code of -22 on my call to avformat_write_header
Note that I can make this work perfectly from the command line version of ffmpeg with the following command:
`ffmpeg -i http://rbmn-live.akamaized.net/hls/live/590964/BoRB-AT/master_1660.m3u8 -vcodec libx264 -f flv rtmp://rtmpserver/streamname`

Comment: Thanks for sharing.. funnily enough I am trying to do the same thing- How did this work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this myself, for anyone who cares. The problem was that the HLS stream had 3 substreams (video, audio and subtitles). The problem is that FLV does not appear to support subtitles and it was detecting this third stream as a second video stream, which is also not supported. So removing this sub-stream from the output stream resulted in a working restreamed video.

Comment: can u send some example please what you have done